# Rust method chaining: call method multiple times with items in a vector

Tags: rust

I want to call an API in a Rust lib (openidconnect-rs) that uses method chaining (methods returning `self`); one of the chained methods should be called once for each element in a vector. This is the example from [openidconnect-rs](https://docs.rs/openidconnect/latest/openidconnect/index.html#example):

```rust
let (auth_url, csrf_token, nonce) = client
    .authorize_url(
        CoreAuthenticationFlow::AuthorizationCode,
        CsrfToken::new_random,
        Nonce::new_random,
    )
    // Set the desired scopes.
    .add_scope(Scope::new("read".to_string()))
    .add_scope(Scope::new("write".to_string()))
    // Set the PKCE code challenge.
    .set_pkce_challenge(pkce_challenge)
    .url();
```

I have a vector of `Scope`s and need to call `add_scope` for each of them. How would one do that? The [definition](https://docs.rs/openidconnect/latest/openidconnect/struct.AuthorizationRequest.html#method.add_scope) of `add_scope` is:

```rust
pub fn add_scope(self, scope: Scope) -> Self
```

It is a method of the [AuthorizationRequest](https://docs.rs/openidconnect/latest/openidconnect/struct.AuthorizationRequest.html#) struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have `scopes : Vec<Scope>`, then something like:

```
let mut auth_req = client.authorize_url(
    CoreAuthenticationFlow::AuthorizationCode,
    CsrfToken::new_random,
    Nonce::new_random,
);

for scope in scopes {
    auth_req = auth_req.add_scope(scope);
}

let (auth_url, csrf_token, nonce) = auth_req.set_pkce_challenge(pkce_challenge).url();
```

should do you fine. The idea being that you can simply update some variable, moving ownership of the `AuthorizationRequest` through the method call, back to the original variable.

Comment: Wow... thanks. I just missed the assignment in the `for` loop
```auth_req = auth_req.add_scope(scope);```